# timeout in Azure functions App binding with events hub to send data

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, azure-eventhub, azure-http-trigger, timer-trigger

I have a nodeJS functions app, in which i have a http trigger function with following code. It runs successfully.

With all the below code and configuration, i am able to send data to events hub from a local functions app and published functions app, the issue which i am facing is when i run function from portal it takes forever to return response and then it gives 500 error, before adding this events hub code it was running fine on portal.

I am following guide from Microsof site but looks like it is not how it should send the message to events hub and i tried adding await to lines sending data, i have also tried commenting context.done(), and i also tried putting it in a function and calling it with await but still all gives me same behavior.

Same behavior i have seen with timer trigger function and it gives me following exception after running. It looks like it is sending the data but then after sometime it gives a timeout.

```
[Error] Executed 'Functions.myfunction' (Failed, Id=, Duration=131873ms)
```

Below is my code before adding events hub code (runs fine on local and portal)

```
module.exports =  async function (context, req) {
context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
try {
const name = (req.query.name || (req.body && req.body.name));
const responseMessage = name
    ? "Hello, " + name + ". This HTTP triggered function executed successfully."
    : "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.";


    // Construct response
    const responseJSON = {
        "message": responseMessage,
        "success": true
    }

    context.res = {
        // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
        body: responseJSON,
        contentType: 'application/json'
    };
} catch(err) {
    context.res = {
        status: 500
    };
}
}
```

I then upgraded my code to following to send data from functions app to events hub [this source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-output?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process%2Cfunctionsv2%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-javascript#example)

```
module.exports =  async function (context, req) {
context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
try {
const name = (req.query.name || (req.body && req.body.name));
const responseMessage = name
    ? "Hello, " + name + ". This HTTP triggered function executed successfully."
    : "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.";


    var timeStamp = new Date().toISOString();
    var message = 'Message created at: ' + timeStamp;

    context.bindings.outputEventHubMessage = [];

    context.bindings.outputEventHubMessage.push("1 " + message);
    context.bindings.outputEventHubMessage.push("2 " + message);
    // context.done();

    // Construct response
    const responseJSON = {
        "message": responseMessage,
        "success": true
    }

    context.res = {
        // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
        body: responseJSON,
        contentType: 'application/json'
    };
} catch(err) {
    context.res = {
        status: 500
    };
}
}
```

I have also added binding of events hub

My functions.json

```
{
      "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "type": "eventHub",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "outputEventHubMessage",
      "connection": "smaseventhubsend_EVENTHUBSETTING",
      "eventHubName": "smaseventhub"
    }
  ]
}
```

My local.settings.json file

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "smaseventhubsend_EVENTHUBSETTING": "Pathtoeventhub with key"
  }
}
```

I have used the diagnose and solve problems and searched for Function and execution errors and noticed the following exception.

```
 Full Exception : Exception while executing function /Functions.EventHubConnectionTest ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException  /Connection timed out    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)    Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Transport.AmqpTransportInitiator.<>c.<ConnectAsync>b__17_1(IAsyncResult r)    System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar,Func`2 endFunction,Action`1 endAction,Task`1 promise,Boolean requiresSynchronization)    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    async Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpConnectionScope.CreateAndOpenConnectionAsync(Version amqpVersion,Uri serviceEndpoint,Uri connectionEndpoint,EventHubsTransportType transportType,IWebProxy proxy,Int32 sendBufferSizeBytes,Int32 receiveBufferSizeBytes,RemoteCertificateValidationCallback certificateValidationCallback,String scopeIdentifier,TimeSpan timeout)    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    async Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.FaultTolerantAmqpObject`1.OnCreateAsync[T](??)    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    async Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.GetOrCreateAsync[TValue](??)    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    async Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.GetOrCreateAsync[TValue](??)    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    async Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpConnectionScope.OpenProducerLinkAsync(String partitionId,TransportProducerFeatures features,PartitionPublishingOptions options,TimeSpan operationTimeout,TimeSpan linkTimeout,String linkIdentifier,CancellationToken cancellationToken)    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    async Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpProducer.CreateLinkAndEnsureProducerStateAsync(String partitionId,String producerIdentifier,PartitionPublishingOptions partitionOptions,TimeSpan timeout,CancellationToken cancellationToken)    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    async Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpProducer.CreateLinkAndEnsureProducerStateAsync(String partitionId,String producerIdentifier,PartitionPublishingOptions partitionOptions,TimeSpan timeout,CancellationToken cancellationToken)    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    async Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.FaultTolerantAmqpObject`1.OnCreateAsync[T](??)    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    async Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.GetOrCreateAsync[TValue](??)    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    async Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.GetOrCreateAsync[TValue](??)    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    async Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpProducer.CreateBatchAsync(CreateBatchOptions options,CancellationToken cancellationToken)    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    async Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpProducer.CreateBatchAsync(CreateBatchOptions options,CancellationToken cancellationToken)    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    async Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Producer.EventHubProducerClient.CreateBatchAsync(??)    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()    async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.EventHubs.EventHubProducerClientImpl.CreateBatchAsync(??)    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.EventHubs.EventHubAsyncCollector.AddAsync(??)    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Bindings.TypedAsyncCollectorAdapter`3.AddAsync[TSrc,TDest,TAttribute](TSrc item,CancellationToken cancellationToken) D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Bindings\AsyncCollector\TypedAsyncCollectorAdapter.cs  /40    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Binding.FunctionBinding.BindAsyncCollectorAsync[T](BindingContext context) /src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script/Binding/FunctionBinding.cs  /200    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Binding.ExtensionBinding.BindAsync(BindingContext context) /src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script/Binding/ExtensionBinding.cs  /80    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.WorkerFunctionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<BindOutputsAsync>b__0(??) /src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script/Description/Workers/WorkerFunctionInvoker.cs  /182    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.WorkerFunctionInvoker.BindOutputsAsync(Object input,Binder binder,ScriptInvocationResult result) /src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script/Description/Workers/WorkerFunctionInvoker.cs  /186    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.WorkerFunctionInvoker.InvokeCore(Object[] parameters,FunctionInvocationContext context) /src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script/Description/Workers/WorkerFunctionInvoker.cs  /109    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.FunctionInvokerBase.Invoke(Object[] parameters) /src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script/Description/FunctionInvokerBase.cs  /82    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.FunctionGenerator.Coerce[T](Task`1 src) /src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script/Description/FunctionGenerator.cs  /225    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2.InvokeAsync[TReflected,TReturnValue](Object instance,Object[] arguments) D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionInvoker.cs  /52    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.InvokeWithTimeoutAsync(IFunctionInvoker invoker,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,CancellationTokenSource timeoutTokenSource,CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource,Boolean throwOnTimeout,TimeSpan timerInterval,IFunctionInstance instance) D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs  /581    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithWatchersAsync(IFunctionInstanceEx instance,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,ILogger logger,CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource) D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs  /527    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(IFunctionInstanceEx instance,FunctionStartedMessage message,FunctionInstanceLogEntry instanceLogEntry,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,ILogger logger,CancellationToken cancellationToken) D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs  /306    End of inner exception    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(IFunctionInstanceEx instance,FunctionStartedMessage message,FunctionInstanceLogEntry instanceLogEntry,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,ILogger logger,CancellationToken cancellationToken) D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs  /352    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.TryExecuteAsync(IFunctionInstance functionInstance,CancellationToken cancellationToken) D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs  /108
```

Answer (score 0):

> from portal it takes forever to return response and then it gives 500 error.

- 500 is a generic error which refers to Internal server error.
- To know exact error details, enable Application insights in your function app.

[image]

- Check if you have configured the *EventHub connection string* in function app properly and re-verify the *eventhub* name.
- Test the same in a new function app in different OS & region.

---

***I have tried to reproduce from my end:***

- Created function app in ***windows*** environment, I was getting the same error.
- I was getting the same error with default Http triggered function.

[image]
[image]

- Created function app in Linux environment, I was able to send the data to event hub using the same code you have provided.

[image]

[image]

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: I have added the exception which i am getting from Diagnose and solve problems using function execution as parameter.

I am using functions App in linux env.